# Pycharm предупреждает, что нельзя конкатенировать кортежи разных типов (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, tuple

Работаю в Pycharm. Пытаюсь добавить элемент в начало кортежа:

```
a = tuple((1, 2, 3, 4))
b = (0,) + a
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Никаких ошибок/предупреждений.

Теперь сделаем кортеж разнотипным:

```
a = tuple((1, 2, '3', 4))
b = (0,) + a
print(b)
```

Pycharm услужливо подсветит переменную `a` во второй строке и в пояснении напишет, что:

```
Unexpected type(s): (tuple[int, int, str, int]) 
Possible type(s): (tuple[int, ...]) (tuple[int, ...])
```

Код при этом работает как ожидается:

```
(0, 1, 2, '3', 4)
```

Я, добился того, что избежал предупреждения и получил, то что надо, только пришлось в изначальный кортеж добавить первый элемент-пустышку, а потом взять слайс:

```
a = tuple((5, 1, 2, '3', 4))
b = (0,) + a[1:5]
print(b)
```

Тогда предупреждений нет и код работает как ожидалось. Но это же костыль.

Пока писал вопрос, нашел еще такое решение:

```
a = tuple((1, 2, '3', 4))
b = (0,) + a[:]
print(b)
```

Так лучше, но все равно не понятно, что не нравится Pycharm.
Поясните, коллеги, что с этим делать, чтобы было красиво.

**Upd.**
Приближаемся к истине. Если тип переменной `a` указать явно, предупреждение пропадает.

```
a: tuple = tuple((1, 2, '3', 4))
b = (0,) + a
print(b)
```

Comment: У меня в PyCharm все работает без предупреждений. Попробуйте так `b = (0,*a)`

Comment: тоже нет никакого предупреждения

Comment: Ваши версии Пайтона и Пайчарма? И вообще, есть мнение почему так может быть? Я пока думаю, что дело в версиях.

Comment: @АлексейР Да, такой вариант рабочий и красивый. Спасибо! Но не объясняет, что не нравится IDE.

Comment: PyCharm 2021.2.3 (Community Edition), Build #PC-212.5457.59, built on October 19, 2021; Python 3.9.7

Comment: Вот здесь по-моему неплохо объяснено: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69898471/8324991

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо! Я пришел к такому же решению, но по вашей ссылке все доходчиво объяснено. А почему у коллег такого предупреждения не появляется? В настройках Pycharm дело?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Видимо, да. Настройки анализатора кода разные.

Comment: к вопросу о красоте. `(1, 2, '3', 4)` - и так tuple, поэтому `tuple((1, 2, '3', 4))` - очень избыточно. Достаточно `a = 1, 2, '3', 4`

Comment: @АлексейР Спасибо!  На будущее учту.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = tuple((1, 2, '3', 4))
b = (0,) + a
print(b)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from typing import Tuple, Any

a: Tuple[Any, ...] = tuple((1, 2, '3', 4))
b = (0,) + a
print(b)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]